# Screen orientation in PhoneGap / Android

Tags: android, cordova, orientation

I'm currently developing a small demo in PhoneGap to test out some functionalities. I want to use the [PhoneGap-OrientationLock plugin available from Github](https://github.com/cogitor/PhoneGap-OrientationLock) to be able to dynamically change my screen orientation from JavaScript, I've updated the plugin to use it in Cordova.

My problem right now is that it crashes as soon as I want to change my screen orientation. Even if I try something as simple as `setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE);` (without using PhoneGap technically) from my onCreate method, my application just quits to the launcher with the following debug log:

```
08-20 08:57:17.083: D/DroidGap(21383): DroidGap.onCreate()
08-20 08:57:17.193: D/CordovaWebView(21383): Origin to allow: http://127.0.0.1*
08-20 08:57:17.193: I/CordovaLog(21383): Found log level DEBUG
08-20 08:57:17.193: I/CordovaLog(21383): Changing log level to DEBUG(3)
08-20 08:57:17.193: I/CordovaLog(21383): Found preference for fullscreen=true
08-20 08:57:17.193: D/CordovaLog(21383): Found preference for fullscreen=true
08-20 08:57:17.193: I/CordovaLog(21383): Found preference for useBrowserHistory=false
08-20 08:57:17.193: D/CordovaLog(21383): Found preference for useBrowserHistory=false
08-20 08:57:17.223: D/DroidGap(21383): DroidGap.init()
08-20 08:57:17.223: D/CordovaWebView(21383): >>> loadUrl(file:///android_asset/www/index.html)
08-20 08:57:17.223: D/PluginManager(21383): init()
08-20 08:57:17.233: D/CordovaWebView(21383): >>> loadUrlNow()
08-20 08:57:17.243: D/CordovaWebView(21383): >>> loadUrlNow()
08-20 08:57:17.243: D/DroidGap(21383): onDestroy()
08-20 08:57:17.243: D/CordovaWebView(21383): >>> loadUrlNow()
08-20 08:57:17.243: D/CordovaWebView(21383): >>> loadUrlNow()
08-20 08:57:17.263: D/DroidGap(21383): DroidGap.onCreate()
08-20 08:57:17.263: D/CordovaWebView(21383): Origin to allow: http://127.0.0.1*
08-20 08:57:17.263: I/CordovaLog(21383): Found log level DEBUG
08-20 08:57:17.263: I/CordovaLog(21383): Changing log level to DEBUG(3)
08-20 08:57:17.263: I/CordovaLog(21383): Found preference for fullscreen=true
08-20 08:57:17.263: D/CordovaLog(21383): Found preference for fullscreen=true
08-20 08:57:17.263: I/CordovaLog(21383): Found preference for useBrowserHistory=false
08-20 08:57:17.263: D/CordovaLog(21383): Found preference for useBrowserHistory=false
08-20 08:57:17.273: D/DroidGap(21383): DroidGap.init()
08-20 08:57:17.273: D/CordovaWebView(21383): >>> loadUrl(file:///android_asset/www/index.html)
08-20 08:57:17.273: D/PluginManager(21383): init()
08-20 08:57:17.293: D/CordovaWebView(21383): >>> loadUrlNow()
08-20 08:57:17.313: D/DroidGap(21383): onMessage(onPageStarted,file:///android_asset/www/index.html)
08-20 08:57:17.313: D/SoftKeyboardDetect(21383): Ignore this event
08-20 08:57:17.373: D/SoftKeyboardDetect(21383): Ignore this event
08-20 08:57:17.483: D/Cordova(21383): onPageFinished(file:///android_asset/www/index.html)
08-20 08:57:17.483: D/CordovaWebView(21383): >>> loadUrlNow()
08-20 08:57:17.483: D/DroidGap(21383): onMessage(onNativeReady,null)
08-20 08:57:17.483: D/DroidGap(21383): onMessage(onPageFinished,file:///android_asset/www/index.html)
08-20 08:57:17.483: D/DroidGap(21383): onMessage(onPageStarted,about:blank)
08-20 08:57:17.503: D/dalvikvm(21383): GC_CONCURRENT freed 326K, 9% free 7566K/8263K, paused 8ms+2ms, total 33ms
08-20 08:57:17.513: D/Cordova(21383): onPageFinished(about:blank)
08-20 08:57:17.513: D/DroidGap(21383): onMessage(onPageFinished,about:blank)
08-20 08:57:17.513: D/DroidGap(21383): onMessage(exit,null)
08-20 08:57:17.563: D/DroidGap(21383): onMessage(onPageStarted,file:///android_asset/www/index.html)
08-20 08:57:17.563: D/CordovaWebView(21383): >>> loadUrlNow()
08-20 08:57:18.023: D/Cordova(21383): onPageFinished(file:///android_asset/www/index.html)
08-20 08:57:18.023: D/CordovaWebView(21383): >>> loadUrlNow()
08-20 08:57:18.023: D/DroidGap(21383): onMessage(onNativeReady,null)
08-20 08:57:18.023: D/DroidGap(21383): onMessage(onPageFinished,file:///android_asset/www/index.html)
08-20 08:57:18.053: E/SQLiteLog(21383): (14) cannot open file at line 30174 of [00bb9c9ce4]
08-20 08:57:18.053: E/SQLiteLog(21383): (14) os_unix.c:30174: (2) open(/CachedGeoposition.db) - 
08-20 08:57:18.053: D/WebKit(21383): ERROR: 
08-20 08:57:18.053: D/WebKit(21383): SQLite database failed to load from /CachedGeoposition.db
08-20 08:57:18.053: D/WebKit(21383): Cause - unable to open database file
08-20 08:57:18.053: D/WebKit(21383): external/webkit/Source/WebCore/platform/sql/SQLiteDatabase.cpp(71) : bool WebCore::SQLiteDatabase::open(const WTF::String&, bool)
08-20 08:57:18.143: D/DroidGap(21383): onMessage(networkconnection,wifi)
08-20 08:57:18.183: D/DroidGap(21383): onMessage(spinner,stop)
08-20 08:57:18.223: W/IInputConnectionWrapper(21383): showStatusIcon on inactive InputConnection
08-20 08:57:18.263: D/DroidGap(21383): onDestroy()
08-20 08:57:18.263: D/CordovaWebView(21383): >>> loadUrlNow()
08-20 08:57:18.263: D/CordovaWebView(21383): >>> loadUrlNow()
08-20 08:57:18.283: D/DroidGap(21383): onMessage(onPageStarted,about:blank)
08-20 08:57:18.303: D/Cordova(21383): onPageFinished(about:blank)
08-20 08:57:18.303: D/DroidGap(21383): onMessage(onPageFinished,about:blank)
08-20 08:57:18.303: D/DroidGap(21383): onMessage(exit,null)
08-20 08:57:19.483: D/DroidGap(21383): onMessage(spinner,stop)
08-20 08:57:19.513: D/DroidGap(21383): onMessage(spinner,stop)
08-20 08:57:20.023: D/DroidGap(21383): onMessage(spinner,stop)
```

So it looks like as soon as I call setRequestedOrientation like so:

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE);
    super.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/www/index.html");
}
```

My application calls onDestroy and goes back to the launcher. Am I just not understanding an Android concept? Anyone has a clue?

Comment: Please see the accepted answer here:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9045933/phonegap-app-crashes-when-switched-orientation-even-with-androidmanifest-changes

Answer (score 5):

You should add  `android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden"` in the Android Manifest in the first `<activity>` that appears. I had the same problem, it crashed my app too.

Comment: Why would you answer a question that's a month old and that I already found a solution. See my comment.

Comment: Because it's nice to have the actual answer with the question, not just a link. Why hate on someone answering your question?