# Phonegap App crashing on Galaxy Note when orientation changes

Tags: javascript, android, cordova

I have a couple of complete phonegap apps, fully functional. I've tried in the whole set of devices I have access to, and it doesn't run on my galaxy note. It's a brand new device, I can run native apps, but whenever I run any phonegap app i get a black screen and the app closes. No crash, no alert, no nothing.

(I remove the logs here because they were not relevant)

**EDIT**

I've tracked down the issue and it works when the orientation changes. As soon as I stat my activity it sets the orientation to portrait.

```
setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT);
```

So I removed that lane, activated the option to change the orientation when I rotate the device. Now when I start the app it runs, but when I rotate it, it crashes. I can't figure out why. I have several alerts in my js code and none of them is fired. The interesting thing is the cordova default app also crashes when I rotate the device. Below you can find both logs.

Any suggestions on how to fix this?

DroidgapExample log:

```
11-27 12:41:15.750: D/DroidGap(9129): Paused the application!
11-27 12:41:15.750: D/CordovaWebView(9129): Handle the pause
11-27 12:41:15.750: D/CordovaWebView(9129): >>> loadUrlNow()
11-27 12:41:15.750: D/webkit(9129): Firewall not null
11-27 12:41:15.750: D/webkit(9129): euler: isUrlBlocked = false
11-27 12:41:15.760: D/DroidGap(9129): onDestroy()
11-27 12:41:15.760: D/CordovaWebView(9129): >>> loadUrlNow()
11-27 12:41:15.760: D/webkit(9129): Firewall not null
11-27 12:41:15.765: D/webkit(9129): euler: isUrlBlocked = false
11-27 12:41:15.765: D/CordovaWebView(9129): >>> loadUrlNow()
11-27 12:41:15.765: D/webkit(9129): Firewall not null
11-27 12:41:15.765: D/webkit(9129): euler: isUrlBlocked = false
11-27 12:41:15.775: D/DroidGap(9129): DroidGap.onCreate()
11-27 12:41:15.780: I/webclipboard(9129): clipservice: android.sec.clipboard.ClipboardExManager@4149bc80
11-27 12:41:15.785: D/CordovaWebView(9129): Origin to allow: http://127.0.0.1*
11-27 12:41:15.785: D/CordovaWebView(9129): Origin to allow: .*
11-27 12:41:15.785: I/CordovaLog(9129): Found log level DEBUG
11-27 12:41:15.785: I/CordovaLog(9129): Changing log level to DEBUG(3)
11-27 12:41:15.785: I/CordovaLog(9129): Found preference for useBrowserHistory=false
11-27 12:41:15.785: D/CordovaLog(9129): Found preference for useBrowserHistory=false
11-27 12:41:15.785: I/CordovaLog(9129): Found preference for exit-on-suspend=false
11-27 12:41:15.785: D/CordovaLog(9129): Found preference for exit-on-suspend=false
11-27 12:41:15.785: D/JsMessageQueue(9129): Set native->JS mode to 1
11-27 12:41:15.785: D/DroidGap(9129): DroidGap.init()
11-27 12:41:15.790: D/CordovaWebView(9129): >>> loadUrl(file:///android_asset/www/index.html)
11-27 12:41:15.790: D/PluginManager(9129): init()
11-27 12:41:15.795: D/CordovaWebView(9129): >>> loadUrlNow()
11-27 12:41:15.800: D/DroidGap(9129): Resuming the App
11-27 12:41:15.800: D/CordovaLog(9129): JSCallback Error: Request failed with status 0
11-27 12:41:15.800: D/CordovaLog(9129): file:///android_asset/www/cordova-2.1.0.js: Line 3743 : JSCallback Error: Request failed with status 0
11-27 12:41:15.800: I/Web Console(9129): JSCallback Error: Request failed with status 0 at file:///android_asset/www/cordova-2.1.0.js:3743
11-27 12:41:15.800: D/JsMessageQueue(9129): Set native->JS mode to 0
11-27 12:41:15.800: D/WML_SISO(9129): InitPasteboardJni
11-27 12:41:15.805: D/SoftKeyboardDetect(9129): Ignore this event
11-27 12:41:15.810: D/SoftKeyboardDetect(9129): Ignore this event
11-27 12:41:15.810: D/JsMessageQueue(9129): Set native->JS mode to 1
11-27 12:41:15.810: D/DroidGap(9129): onMessage(onPageStarted,about:blank)
11-27 12:41:15.820: W/webcore(9129): java.lang.Throwable: EventHub.removeMessages(int what = 107) is not supported before the WebViewCore is set up.
11-27 12:41:15.820: W/webcore(9129):    at android.webkit.WebViewCore$EventHub.removeMessages(WebViewCore.java:2681)
11-27 12:41:15.820: W/webcore(9129):    at android.webkit.WebViewCore$EventHub.access$13000(WebViewCore.java:1365)
11-27 12:41:15.820: W/webcore(9129):    at android.webkit.WebViewCore.removeMessages(WebViewCore.java:2793)
11-27 12:41:15.820: W/webcore(9129):    at android.webkit.WebView.sendOurVisibleRect(WebView.java:4046)
11-27 12:41:15.820: W/webcore(9129):    at android.webkit.ZoomManager.setZoomScale(ZoomManager.java:1024)
11-27 12:41:15.820: W/webcore(9129):    at android.webkit.ZoomManager.access$2100(ZoomManager.java:57)
11-27 12:41:15.820: W/webcore(9129):    at android.webkit.ZoomManager$PostScale.run(ZoomManager.java:1595)
11-27 12:41:15.820: W/webcore(9129):    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:605)
11-27 12:41:15.820: W/webcore(9129):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
11-27 12:41:15.820: W/webcore(9129):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
11-27 12:41:15.820: W/webcore(9129):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4517)
11-27 12:41:15.820: W/webcore(9129):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
11-27 12:41:15.820: W/webcore(9129):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
11-27 12:41:15.820: W/webcore(9129):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:995)
11-27 12:41:15.820: W/webcore(9129):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:762)
11-27 12:41:15.820: W/webcore(9129):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
11-27 12:41:15.820: D/SoftKeyboardDetect(9129): Ignore this event
11-27 12:41:15.825: I/GATE(9129): <GATE-M>DEV_ACTION_COMPLETED</GATE-M>
11-27 12:41:15.830: V/(9129): NotificationPresenterImpl::setSettingsValue 0 
11-27 12:41:15.830: V/(9129): NotificationPresenterImpl::setSettingsValue 0 
11-27 12:41:15.835: D/webkit(9129): Firewall not null
11-27 12:41:15.835: D/webkit(9129): euler: isUrlBlocked = false
11-27 12:41:15.845: D/Cordova(9129): onPageFinished(about:blank)
11-27 12:41:15.845: D/DroidGap(9129): onMessage(onPageFinished,about:blank)
11-27 12:41:15.845: D/DroidGap(9129): onMessage(exit,null)
11-27 12:41:15.900: I/GATE(9129): <GATE-M>DEV_ACTION_COMPLETED</GATE-M>
11-27 12:41:16.245: D/DroidGap(9129): onMessage(onPageStarted,file:///android_asset/www/index.html)
11-27 12:41:16.245: D/Cordova(9129): onPageFinished(file:///android_asset/www/index.html)
11-27 12:41:16.245: D/CordovaWebView(9129): >>> loadUrlNow()
11-27 12:41:16.245: D/webkit(9129): Firewall not null
11-27 12:41:16.245: D/webkit(9129): euler: isUrlBlocked = false
11-27 12:41:16.245: D/DroidGap(9129): onMessage(onNativeReady,null)
11-27 12:41:16.245: D/DroidGap(9129): onMessage(onPageFinished,file:///android_asset/www/index.html)
11-27 12:41:16.250: D/DroidGap(9129): Paused the application!
11-27 12:41:16.250: D/CordovaWebView(9129): Handle the pause
11-27 12:41:16.250: D/CordovaWebView(9129): >>> loadUrlNow()
11-27 12:41:16.360: D/DroidGap(9129): onMessage(networkconnection,wifi)
11-27 12:41:16.370: D/DroidGap(9129): onMessage(spinner,stop)
11-27 12:41:16.375: D/webkit(9129): Firewall not null
11-27 12:41:16.375: D/webkit(9129): euler: isUrlBlocked = false
11-27 12:41:16.380: D/CordovaLog(9129): Received Event: deviceready
11-27 12:41:16.380: D/CordovaLog(9129): file:///android_asset/www/js/index.js: Line 47 : Received Event: deviceready
11-27 12:41:16.380: I/Web Console(9129): Received Event: deviceready at file:///android_asset/www/js/index.js:47
11-27 12:41:17.635: D/DroidGap(9129): onDestroy()
11-27 12:41:17.635: D/CordovaWebView(9129): >>> loadUrlNow()
11-27 12:41:17.640: D/webkit(9129): Firewall not null
11-27 12:41:17.640: D/CordovaWebView(9129): >>> loadUrlNow()
11-27 12:41:17.640: D/webkit(9129): euler: isUrlBlocked = false
11-27 12:41:17.640: D/webkit(9129): Firewall not null
11-27 12:41:17.640: D/webkit(9129): euler: isUrlBlocked = false
11-27 12:41:17.650: D/CordovaLog(9129): JSCallback Error: Request failed with status 0
11-27 12:41:17.650: D/CordovaLog(9129): file:///android_asset/www/cordova-2.1.0.js: Line 3743 : JSCallback Error: Request failed with status 0
11-27 12:41:17.650: I/Web Console(9129): JSCallback Error: Request failed with status 0 at file:///android_asset/www/cordova-2.1.0.js:3743
11-27 12:41:17.650: D/JsMessageQueue(9129): Set native->JS mode to 0
11-27 12:41:17.650: D/JsMessageQueue(9129): Set native->JS mode to 1
11-27 12:41:17.660: D/DroidGap(9129): onMessage(onPageStarted,about:blank)
11-27 12:41:17.670: I/GATE(9129): <GATE-M>DEV_ACTION_COMPLETED</GATE-M>
11-27 12:41:17.670: D/Cordova(9129): onPageFinished(about:blank)
11-27 12:41:17.670: D/DroidGap(9129): onMessage(onPageFinished,about:blank)
11-27 12:41:17.670: D/DroidGap(9129): onMessage(exit,null)
11-27 12:41:18.255: D/DroidGap(9129): onMessage(spinner,stop)
```

My App log:

```
11-27 12:36:41.810: D/DroidGap(10500): Paused the application!
11-27 12:36:41.810: D/CordovaWebView(10500): Handle the pause
11-27 12:36:41.810: D/CordovaWebView(10500): >>> loadUrlNow()
11-27 12:36:41.810: D/webkit(10500): Firewall not null
11-27 12:36:41.810: D/webkit(10500): euler: isUrlBlocked = false
11-27 12:36:41.815: D/DroidGap(10500): onDestroy()
11-27 12:36:41.850: D/CordovaWebView(10500): >>> loadUrlNow()
11-27 12:36:41.850: D/webkit(10500): Firewall not null
11-27 12:36:41.850: D/CordovaWebView(10500): >>> loadUrlNow()
11-27 12:36:41.850: D/webkit(10500): euler: isUrlBlocked = false
11-27 12:36:41.855: D/webkit(10500): Firewall not null
11-27 12:36:41.860: D/webkit(10500): euler: isUrlBlocked = false
11-27 12:36:41.865: D/DroidGap(10500): DroidGap.onCreate()
11-27 12:36:41.875: I/webclipboard(10500): clipservice: android.sec.clipboard.ClipboardExManager@4138e4e0
11-27 12:36:41.880: I/CordovaLog(10500): config.xml missing, reverting to cordova.xml
11-27 12:36:41.880: D/CordovaWebView(10500): Origin to allow: http://127.0.0.1*
11-27 12:36:41.880: I/CordovaLog(10500): Found log level DEBUG
11-27 12:36:41.880: I/CordovaLog(10500): Changing log level to DEBUG(3)
11-27 12:36:41.880: I/CordovaLog(10500): Found preference for classicRender=true
11-27 12:36:41.880: D/CordovaLog(10500): Found preference for classicRender=true
11-27 12:36:41.880: D/JsMessageQueue(10500): Set native->JS mode to 1
11-27 12:36:41.895: D/DroidGap(10500): DroidGap.init()
11-27 12:36:41.900: D/CordovaWebView(10500): >>> loadUrl(file:///android_asset/www/page_A_0.html)
11-27 12:36:41.900: D/PluginManager(10500): init()
11-27 12:36:41.900: I/PluginManager(10500): Using plugins.xml instead of config.xml.  plugins.xml will eventually be deprecated
11-27 12:36:41.905: D/CordovaWebView(10500): >>> loadUrlNow()
11-27 12:36:41.910: D/DroidGap(10500): Resuming the App
11-27 12:36:41.915: I/GATE(10500): <GATE-M>DEV_ACTION_COMPLETED</GATE-M>
11-27 12:36:41.915: D/CordovaLog(10500): exception firing pause event from native
11-27 12:36:41.915: D/CordovaLog(10500): null: Line 1 : exception firing pause event from native
11-27 12:36:41.915: I/Web Console(10500): exception firing pause event from native at null:1
11-27 12:36:41.915: D/CordovaLog(10500): exception firing destroy event from native
11-27 12:36:41.915: D/CordovaLog(10500): null: Line 1 : exception firing destroy event from native
11-27 12:36:41.915: I/Web Console(10500): exception firing destroy event from native at null:1
11-27 12:36:41.915: W/System.err(10500): java.net.SocketException: Socket closed
11-27 12:36:41.915: W/System.err(10500):    at libcore.io.Posix.accept(Native Method)
11-27 12:36:41.915: W/System.err(10500):    at libcore.io.BlockGuardOs.accept(BlockGuardOs.java:55)
11-27 12:36:41.915: W/System.err(10500):    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.accept(PlainSocketImpl.java:98)
11-27 12:36:41.915: W/System.err(10500):    at java.net.ServerSocket.implAccept(ServerSocket.java:202)
11-27 12:36:41.915: W/System.err(10500):    at java.net.ServerSocket.accept(ServerSocket.java:127)
11-27 12:36:41.920: W/System.err(10500):    at org.apache.cordova.CallbackServer.run(CallbackServer.java:195)
11-27 12:36:41.920: W/System.err(10500):    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:856)
11-27 12:36:41.920: D/DroidGap(10500): onMessage(onPageStarted,about:blank)
11-27 12:36:41.920: D/WML_SISO(10500): InitPasteboardJni
11-27 12:36:41.920: D/SoftKeyboardDetect(10500): Ignore this event
11-27 12:36:41.920: V/(10500): NotificationPresenterImpl::setSettingsValue 0 
11-27 12:36:41.920: V/(10500): NotificationPresenterImpl::setSettingsValue 0 
11-27 12:36:41.925: D/webkit(10500): Firewall not null
11-27 12:36:41.925: D/webkit(10500): euler: isUrlBlocked = false
11-27 12:36:41.930: D/SoftKeyboardDetect(10500): Ignore this event
11-27 12:36:41.935: D/Cordova(10500): onPageFinished(about:blank)
11-27 12:36:41.935: D/DroidGap(10500): onMessage(onPageFinished,about:blank)
11-27 12:36:41.935: D/DroidGap(10500): onMessage(exit,null)
11-27 12:36:41.970: D/chromium(10500): Unknown chromium error: -6
11-27 12:36:42.315: D/DroidGap(10500): onMessage(onPageStarted,file:///android_asset/www/page_A_0.html)
11-27 12:36:42.315: D/SoftKeyboardDetect(10500): Ignore this event
11-27 12:36:42.360: D/DroidGap(10500): Paused the application!
11-27 12:36:42.360: D/CordovaWebView(10500): Handle the pause
11-27 12:36:42.360: D/CordovaWebView(10500): >>> loadUrlNow()
11-27 12:36:42.555: W/IInputConnectionWrapper(10500): showStatusIcon on inactive InputConnection
11-27 12:36:43.465: D/DroidGap(10500): onDestroy()
11-27 12:36:43.465: D/CordovaWebView(10500): >>> loadUrlNow()
11-27 12:36:43.465: D/CordovaWebView(10500): >>> loadUrlNow()
11-27 12:36:43.480: E/WindowManager(10500): Activity co.uk.precedent.tesco.CordovaTuxedoActivity has leaked window com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView@41449660 that was originally added here
11-27 12:36:43.480: E/WindowManager(10500): android.view.WindowLeaked: Activity co.uk.precedent.tesco.CordovaTuxedoActivity has leaked window com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView@41449660 that was originally added here
11-27 12:36:43.480: E/WindowManager(10500):     at android.view.ViewRootImpl.<init>(ViewRootImpl.java:414)
11-27 12:36:43.480: E/WindowManager(10500):     at android.view.WindowManagerImpl.addView(WindowManagerImpl.java:282)
11-27 12:36:43.480: E/WindowManager(10500):     at android.view.WindowManagerImpl.addView(WindowManagerImpl.java:218)
11-27 12:36:43.480: E/WindowManager(10500):     at android.view.WindowManagerImpl$CompatModeWrapper.addView(WindowManagerImpl.java:143)
11-27 12:36:43.480: E/WindowManager(10500):     at android.view.Window$LocalWindowManager.addView(Window.java:548)
11-27 12:36:43.480: E/WindowManager(10500):     at android.app.Dialog.show(Dialog.java:337)
11-27 12:36:43.480: E/WindowManager(10500):     at android.app.AlertDialog$Builder.show(AlertDialog.java:932)
11-27 12:36:43.480: E/WindowManager(10500):     at org.apache.cordova.CordovaChromeClient.onJsAlert(CordovaChromeClient.java:119)
11-27 12:36:43.480: E/WindowManager(10500):     at android.webkit.CallbackProxy.handleMessage(CallbackProxy.java:628)
11-27 12:36:43.480: E/WindowManager(10500):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
11-27 12:36:43.480: E/WindowManager(10500):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
11-27 12:36:43.480: E/WindowManager(10500):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4517)
11-27 12:36:43.480: E/WindowManager(10500):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
11-27 12:36:43.480: E/WindowManager(10500):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
11-27 12:36:43.480: E/WindowManager(10500):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:995)
11-27 12:36:43.480: E/WindowManager(10500):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:762)
11-27 12:36:43.480: E/WindowManager(10500):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: any luck fixing the problem? I have a similar problem on Google Nexus S phone.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've sorted this a while ago, with [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9045933/phonegap-app-crashes-when-switched-orientation-even-with-androidmanifest-changes).

adding the screenSize property to my config changes attribute in every activity solved the problem. Bear in mind it was added in API level 13.

```
android:configChanges="orientation|screenSize|keyboardHidden"
```

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, it isn't a device compatibility issue - I have a Galaxy Note here that runs PhoneGap apps without any problems.

Have you tried running the default Cordova template app to rule out more complex app-specific issues?

The firewall messages suggest that your app is trying to load something over the network during startup - your question doesn't give any information on what that might be, but it shouldn't be too hard to track down.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I've updated my question with more details on my problem!