# Application crash while switching changing the mode (Landscape & portrait )in jquery mobile android

Tags: jquery-mobile, cordova

I am using jquery mobile .I am facing one problem .Actually my application is crash when i switch to landscape to portrait  mode .Is there any java code required to  support both mode .or use media query ..?This is happening only in android.How to handle that ?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add `android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden"` to `activity` tag in your android manifest file.

Refer these

[Phonegap app crashes when switched orientation even with AndroidManifest changes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9045933/phonegap-app-crashes-when-switched-orientation-even-with-androidmanifest-changes)

http://groups.google.com/group/phonegap/msg/c771fffc4dd9daaf

http://community.phonegap.com/nitobi/topics/app_crashes_on_android_during_orientation_change

If that won't work, better **post your android manifest code.**